# Why could I answer a closed question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I've started writing an answer for this question: [How to wrap elements populated by array of objects in pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67301738/how-to-wrap-elements-populated-by-array-of-objects-in-pairs/67302277#67302277) and when I submitted it, I noticed it had been closed 30 minutes ago.

Usually, when this happens, I see an orange warning on top of the page and I'm not able to submit my answer. Can someone explain why I could submit it this time?